# Using iPad with cloud9-ide (terminal keyboard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipad, cloud9-ide

I have read all of the posts about c9 being a very poor experience on a touch device but most of the posts are based on being unable to access the file structure (dbl click).
Has anyone been able to use the terminal from an iPad keyboard? I have a light rails app that I can leave most of the tabs open (saving the dbl click issue) but cannot use a KB in the terminal which means being unable to run the rails console or my app easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACE editor used in Cloud9 does not properly work on mobile devices yet. There is an [issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/37) open to add that but as far as I know it is not currently being worked on. We are considering to create a stripped down IDE for mobile at some point but we don't have an ETA for it yet.